# How to display something after a certain date?

Tags: wordpress

I have a theme. 
After 14th Nov 2019, I want use this code:

```
     <?php the_field('new-class-name'); ?>
```

before 14th Nov 2019 I want use this code:

```
     <?php the_field('class'); ?>
```

as my limited PHP knowledge, I think should be something like this.

```
    <?php                                    
    $date = get_post_meta($post->ID);                                                       
    $thedate = 14-01-2019;                                       
    if ( $date > $thedate ) {                                            
    <?php the_field('new-class-name'); ?>                                        
    } else {                                            
    <?php echo( $date ); ?>                                      
    }                                        
    ?>
    <?php
```

Thanks for WhereDidMyBrainGo reply, it works now, but just shows **new-class-name**, **class** shows nothing. That is to say,all the posts published before 01/12/2019 did not show up.

```
    <?php                               
     $thedate = strtotime('01/12/2019');
     $post_date = get_the_date( 'm/d/Y' ); 
     if ( $post_date < $thedate ) {
        the_field('new-class-name');                                        
        } else {                                            
         the_field('class');
        }  
    ?>
```

Comment: `strtotime('01/12/2019')` => will return timestamps, `get_the_date( 'm/d/Y' )` => will return the date in the format you provided as parameter that makes nonsense, so use `$post_date = strtotime(get_the_date( 'm/d/Y' ));` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After 14th Nov 2019, I want use this code: the_field('new-class-name');

```
$thedate = strtotime('11/14/2019');
  if ( $thedate < time() ) {
     the_field('new-class-name');                                        
  } else {                                            
     the_field('class');
  }`
```

[strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) is used for comparison with [current time](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php).

Best wishes,
Mitchell

Comment: Thanks for  reply, it works now, but still have some problem. Please see the new code above.